# “To maintain influence over domestic bulls, buffaloes etc,..”

Tags: word-request, difference

[image]

What do you call the rope across the head? (not the rest the man is holding). Is it ‘tether’, or ‘bridle’?

Answer (score 1):

I'd understand "bridle" but the technical term is *halter*:

> a strap or rope placed around the head of a horse or other animal, used for leading or tethering it. (Lexico)

The main difference between a bridle and halter is that a bridle is for riding, but a halter is for leading an animal. Bridles usually attach to a "bit" that goes in the animals mouth.